# Why does my vector file gets pixelated when I apply the "Plastic Wrap" effect in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a vector file that gets pixelated when i apply the "plastic wrap" effect. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Plastic wrap is a raster filter. Therefore it creates a raster image.

You can increase the **Document Raster Effect Settings** in the `Effects` menu to improve the appearance of raster effects.

Be aware: A high PPI setting will tend to slow down Illustrator and will increase this slowing with the more raster effects used in the document.